Is Null Checking Necessary in TypeScript for Runtime Safety?
TypeScript types are only enforced at compile time and do not exist at runtime. Given this, if I define a TypeScript function that accepts a string parameter, is it necessary to perform null checks? This question arises because if the API returns null, it could lead to runtime errors.
Consider the following code snippet:
const capitalise = (val: string) => {
   // Question: Is this check redundant due to TypeScript's type checking?
   if (!val) {
      return '';
   }

   return val.toUpperCase();
};

// Assume 'name' is fetched from an API or another source that could return null
const name: string = /* fetch from API or another source */;

capitalise(name);

What are the best practices in such scenarios to ensure runtime safety in TypeScript applications?

The code you've left out after const name: string = is the important bit, and where the problem is if that code could return null but somehow isn't typed properly. Please provide a [mre] that shows what's going on there. If you allow one place in your code to assign null to a variable of type string then all bets are off and sure, you could start null-checking everywhere, but that defeats the purpose of TS.

Obviously the capitalise function should not work with non-strings, and if it can get null from the api, then this is a wrong typing of the api. I think the right solution is to correctly type the API method, give it the null | string type, then add a handler that will either call capitalise (or code where capitalise is used) or give an error. And what are the best practices for handling api errors is a topic for a separate question.
